# Open a template file and go to a start line then print out a database query results

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I got something similar to this, to work in another program by doing the following:

```
        with open (OutputFileName, 'r') as OutputFile:
            for line in islice(OutputFile, StartCount):
                pass
            for line in islice(OutputFile,int(FQuantity)):
                data= line.strip().split("  ")
```

So the above did what i wanted it to, it openned a existing template file skipped to the StartCount and started writing out stuff.

however this time im trying to skip to a startcount and print out database results. No matter how i try for some reason i cant get it to actually skip rows anymore; see attempts below:

where numberlist is the data result from database. I think this one doesnt work because i leave the islice.

```
        with open(InputOrderARCpathcreate, 'r+') as inputfile:
            for line in islice(inputfile, StartCount):
                pass
            for row in numberlist:
                inputfile.write(str(row[0]) + '\n')
```

other attempt where i try smthn closer to what worked before, using a quantity:-

```
        with open(InputOrderARCpathcreate, 'r+') as inputfile:
        for line in islice(inputfile, StartCount):
            pass
        for line in islice (inputfile, 1):
            for row in numberlist:
                inputfile.write(str(row[0]) + '\n')
```

I want to know the following:

1. how can I get this to work my way? (even if it isnt the best way i want to understand why it doesnt work.
2. How can i do something like this overall even if not using islice?

Answer (score 0):

so i figured out another way to do it myself. As for why it wasnt working i was only able to understand that the islice way only works for me to read the data but doesnt for writing im sure theres more to that but yea. See my solution below:

```
    with open(InputOrderARCpathcreate, 'r') as inputfile:
        inputfilelines = inputfile.readlines()
        with open(InputOrderARCpathcreate, 'w+') as inputfile:
            for row in numberlist:
                i=0
                inputfilelines[StartCount+i] = str(row[0]) + '\n'
                i+=1
            inputfile.writelines(inputfilelines)
```